# Is there a way to calculate the average of different rows for a specific column in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
#column #column2  #column3....#column10

A,        2010,     1231
A,        2011,     1235
A,        2012,     1233
A,        2014,     1234 
A,        2015,     1231
B,        2010,     1423
B,        2011,     1423
```

Is there a code to find the average of column3 to 10 for A,B,... Z?

Comment: See pandas groupby  method.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the table you're using is a pandas data frame. Let us say that the name of the data frame is df and the name of the first column is 'column 1'. I 've used first column because that is the one that contains values - A,B,---Z. Following code should help you out.

```
import pandas as pd
df.groupby(['column_name']).mean()
```

Comment: hey thank you for the response. This helped a lot. Is there a way to extract the data based on the latest year too?

Comment: I did df = df.iloc[df.groupby('column namee')['Year'].idxmax().values.ravel()]